# Error in code, a method to compute sqrt (a)

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

> One of the methods to compute sqrt(a), a>0 is
>
> ```
> X(n+1) = (a + (X(n)*X(n-1))/(X(n)+X(n-1)), n = 1, 2, …,
> ```
>
> with `X0=1` and `X1=a` (That is, it is known that `lim n-> infin of Xn = sqrt(a)`
>
> Write a function `[sqa, nitr] = mySqrt(a)` which implements this calculation. The function should use a while-loop, terminate when the difference between Xn+1 and Xn becomes smaller than `eps(10*a)`, and output Xn+1 in `sqa` and the value of n at which the while-loop was terminated in `nitr`. Test your function for `a = 103041`.

I have written this but it does not work

```
function [sqa, nitr] = mySqrt (a)
%[sqa, nitr] = mySqrt (a)
% computes square root of a 
% sqa = a;
sqaprev = a;
nitr = 0;
X(n+1) = (a + (X(n)*X(n-1))/(X(n)+X(n-1))); %find the second term
sqa= X(n+1)
while abs (sqaprev-sqa) >= eps (10*a)
    sqaprev = sqa;
    sqa = (1/2) *(sqaprev+ (a/sqaprev));
    nitr = nitr + 1;
end %while
end
```

i get the error:

```
Unrecognized function or variable 'X'.
Error in mySqrt (line 7)
X(n+1) = (a + (X(n)*X(n-1))/(X(n)+X(n-1))); %find the second term
```

Could someone help me ?

Comment: What is the question? “It doesn’t work” is not a question. It also is not a good problem statement. Instead, show what happened (error message, wrong result, etc) and show what you did to find the problem. This will make it more likely for you to get an answer. See [ask].

Comment: Okay i have written the error

Comment: Of course, you index into `X` but never define it. What is the value of `X(n)` at the beginning of your code? It doesn’t exist!

Comment: how can i write it?

Comment: It seems to me that the point of your homework is to figure that out. I would recommend that you start at the beginning, since you are missing some basic concepts: https://matlabacademy.mathworks.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should start with declaring your variables and assigning them values

```
X(1)=1;
X(2)=a;
n=2;
```

Then in the loop you apply the given recursion formula, not the Heron/Babylonian formula that got from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

According to the algorithm you presented for the square root, you can try the code below

```
function [sqa, n] = mySqrt(a)
n = 2; % start from 2
X = [1,a]; % initial value for sequence X
while true % repeat procedure until termination condition is reached
    X(n+1) = (a + (X(n)*X(n-1)))/(X(n)+X(n-1)); % update sequence X by assigning new values
    if abs(X(n+1)-X(n)) <= eps(10*a) % termination condition
      break;
    end
    n = n + 1;
end 
sqa = X(end); % return the last element of X as the square root
end
```

such that

```
>> [sqa,n] = mySqrt(a)
sqa =  321.00
n =  20
```