# Trying to create a MATLAB function, including a while-loop, that calculates the square root of a value

Tags: matlab, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to create a MATLAB function which computes the square root of any positive number, using this formula:

x(n+1) = (a + x(n)*x(n-1))/(x(n)+x(n-1))

and also tells me the value of n at which the while-loop in my function is terminated.

I managed to create a function that seemed to work fine at first, when I input 16 and 100. However, when I input values who's root is not an integer the function failed to yield any solutions.

```
function [sqa, nitr] = mySqrt(a) 
n = 0; 
sqa = (a+(n)*(n-1))/((n)+(n-1)); 
while abs(sqa - n) >=  eps(10*a) 
    n = n + 1; 
    if n == 0  
    sqa = 1; 
    nitr = 0; 
    elseif n == 1 
    sqa = a; 
    nitr = 1; 
    else 
    sqa = (a+(n)*(n-1))/((n)+(n-1)) 
nitr = n; 
end 
end
```

```
>> [sqa, nitr] = mySqrt(100) 

sqa =

    10


nitr =

    10

>> [sqa, nitr] = mySqrt(5)
```

When I input a value who's root is not an integer, the function does not come to completion and I have to end it manually. I have not been able to figure out the reason for this.

Comment: this might be an answer for your https://stackoverflow.com/a/60396759/12158757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that n is just a counter, not the result. Try this ( I'm typing this on my phone, so excuse an small typos)

```
function [x2, iteration] = mySqrt(a) 

x1 = 1;
x2 = 1;
iteration = 0;

while abs( x2*x2 - a ) > 10*a*eps
    iteration = iteration + 1;

    x0 = x1;
    x1 = x2;

    x2 = ( a + x1*x2 ) / ( x1+x2 );
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is only checking integers `n=n+1` , so it can only get integers as answers. There is nothing to stop it should it overshoot the answer so the loop will continue indefinitely.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Will I have to completely rethink my function or are there slight tweaks that could fix this?

Comment: Actually looking at Thomas' reference, I've misunderstood the method, your issue is that you're using n in the place of x(n), which you should generate as a sequence